# Show Lipschitz condition for $f(x) = x+|x|$

Tags: lipschitz-functions

I am struggling to prove $$x+|x|$$ to be locally Lipschitz. Since it is not continuously differentiable - not differentiable at $x=0$ - it is hence not globally Lipschitz. But how do I proceed for the local case?

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \leq L|x-y|$$
$$\Rightarrow |x+|x|-y-|y||=...$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x+|x|-y-|y||=|(x-y)+(|x|-|y|)|\le |x-y|+||x|-|y|| \le |x-y|+|x-y| = 2|x-y|$. Thus $k = 2$. The key inequality is $xy \le |xy| = |x||y|$ which leads to $||x| - |y|| \le |x-y|$ which can be shown by simply squaring both sides.

Comment: I must have started completely wrong...
what I did was:
$f'(x) = 1 + \dfrac{x}{|x|}$

Comment: @mathsnovice: Yes, I think you forgot the triangle inequality...

Comment: I am still new to this and I have a question:
For the case of $x^2$, what I did was $\text{sup}\dfrac{|x^2-y^2|}{|x-y|} = \text{sup}|x+y|=\infty$. I understand this completely.
But I don't understand how can you add the term $||x|-|y||$ on the RHS of the inequality. Is that because we could try to create an inequality that will eventually lead to the Lipschitz form $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq L|x-y|$?

Comment: @mathsnovice: That term comes from the triangle inequality, and yes you are right about the intention to create a situation that leads to the $L|x-y|$

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure if I am doing it right if the first term is an $x^2$, i.e. $f = x^2 + |x|$:
$|x^2+|x| - y^2 - |y|| = |x^2-y^2+(|x|-|y|) \leq |x-y|(|x+y|+1)$, $L$ here is then $L=(|x+y|+1)$ which is unbounded and is therefore locally Lipschitz. I can reason it from its sketch but not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @mathsnovice: Ah, for the new one $f(x) = x^2+|x|$, you don't have global Lipschitz but you do have local Lipschitz on a bounded interval.

Comment: I tried to come up with some sort of inequality just like how you did when $x$ is linear.  
$|x^2+|x| - y^2 - |y|| = |x^2-y^2+(|x|-|y|) \leq |x-y|(|x+y|+1)$, $L$ here is then $L=(|x+y|+1)$
Does this look right? 

Comment: @mathsnovice: $L$ must be constant.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x+|x|=\max\{0,2x\}$, so it's globally Lipschitz with constant 2.